# Is remoting a suitable solution for this scenario?

Tags: c#, client-server, remoting

I need a solution where an instance of an object containing configuration information is hosted in a windows service and many (up to 1000) or more simultaneous clients interact with this object.

Clients will access the object on startup and periodically during operation when the client performs its purpose.
Clients will rarely update the config.
Changes to the config must be communicated/reflected on all clients when they occur (no polling).

Is remoting a suitable solution for this? I hoped to avoid writing a full server & client system, dealing with sockets etc.

Comment: You should simply use WCF. Use one of the high-performance bindings like binary over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, remoting is a suitable solution, however if you are using .NET 3.5 or above, you may consider using WCF which surpass remoting, and use nettcp binding.

Comment: I will be using .NET 4.0 so I will read up on WCF, thank you for the answer. I believe this to be the most suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use SQL database for such use, like SQL Server or MySQL and add thin layer of server application (e.g. simple ASP.net application serving XML/JSON data) and scripts / application continuously querying the server.

Comment: Thank you for this, I should have pointed out that I wanted to avoid using a database solution if I can. The amount of information is very small and I didn't want to add SQL as a requisite if I could get away with it.

Comment: I understand, still even for smaller projects with many clients, SQL (or some NoSQL) databases give you atomic synchronisation for parallel queries out of the box, which is nice.

Answer (score -1):

WCF and SQL databases are both solutions worth considering but IMHO what you are describing is more closely related to [remote procedure calling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (RPC). RPC allows you to create a single object on a server which clients can interact with as if it were a local object (so completely avoid the need to deal with sockets). Alternatively each client can also create its own unique server object to interact with.

A full implementation of RPC can be found in the network library [networkcomms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net). The following code snippet is taken from the RPC example.

Server side:

```
//Register a single object server side called "Calculator"
RemoteProcedureCalls.Server.RegisterInstanceForPublicRemoteCall<MathClass, IMath>(new MathClass(), "Calculator");
```

Client side:

```
//Get a reference to the remote object named "Calculator"
IMath calc = RemoteProcedureCalls.Client.CreateProxyToPublicNamedInstance<IMath>(connection, "Calculator", out instanceId);
//We can now use the calculator object as if it were local
//The following WriteLine outputs '12' where the calculation was performed on the server
Console.WriteLine(calc.Multiply(4, 3));
```

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for this library.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Your library certainly looks impressive and the RPC functionality would certainly do what I need, however, I cannot guarantee that I will in future be able to comply with the GPL licencing of the product so I will investigate a WCF based solution first. But thank you.

Comment: @Ashigore - Should you ever get to that point non-GPL licenses are also available, http://www.networkcomms.net/licensing/.

Comment: I didn't see that, the costs seem reasonable too, I will seriously consider using this as a solution instead. Thank you.

Comment: Although the OP describes RPC, I see no reason to believe that is what he _needs_